# Is incorrect data type a fault?

Tags: testing, terminology

As fault is a cause of an error, is incorrect data type (e.g. causing overflow) considered a fault?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the incorrect data type for a value is an error.

With your terminology, yes, that would be considered a fault.

Data types are important - they should be selected for by the expected values that system will produce.

Answer (score 0):

In a strongly typed language, the compiler doesn't allow you to compile code that has a type error. In contrast, dynamically typed languages may compile, but at run-time incorrect data type may result in incorrect/unwanted results. In some languages (eg. Java) an exception is thrown and if  not handled the application is terminated.

Comment: No compiler ever (except for ultra-safe research languages perhaps, but those probably won't have fixed size integers in the first place) would complain about using a 16 bit integer to count the number of bytes in an NTFS file.